# ROS2 building with dependencies

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm new in ROS2 and I lost myself in the dependencies tree.
I have a big project I would like to translate to ROS2.
When I create the my_package my_node it creates a standart structure. How can I add there all python files I need?
There's no chance I can run the whole project using only one python file.
Is there some examples I can learn from?
Thank all of you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390865/ros2-building-with-dependencies/) by [MLEV](https://answers.ros.org/users/89654/mlev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2021-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

You can have as many packages, and as many python files you want. All you need to do is structure your workspace correctly.

After creating a package, you can create .py files inside of `your_workspace/src/my_package/my_package`.

Don't forget to make the files executable with `chmod +x`, and to include them as an entry point in your `setup.py`:

```
    entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        ' [executable_name] = [package_name].[executable]:main',
    ],
```

You can add as many python files as you want this way. I'll be uploading a video tomorrow showing this process in our channel, https://youtu.be/HV7f3ayQMXw, so check it out if you get stuck from what I explained above, and also if you want to see how to add launch files to your `setup.py` as well.

---

Originally posted by [rodrigo55](https://answers.ros.org/users/53015/rodrigo55/) with karma: 156 on 2021-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2021-11-16**:
also for a dependencies tree, don't forget to use colcon

```
colcon graph
```